# How to solve a "HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found" error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, iis-7, wcf, http-status-code-404

Simple problem. I start up VS2008 and create a new WCF Service application. This will create a default application with a few test methods showing it works. I press CTRL+F5 and it does indeed work! Great! However, it uses the Visual Studio Development server, which I don't want to support.

So I go to the project properties, switch to using a local IIS Web server, create the virtual directory and press CTRL+F5 again. And this "HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found" error is greeting me back.

So something in my IIS7/Vista-64 setup is wrong. What could I be missing?

Comment: Found http://iweb.adefwebserver.com/Default.aspx?tabid=57&EntryID=34 which solved my problem. Leaving this open for others to add other possible options to fix this "problem".

Comment: write that up as an answer and mark it accepted to make it clearer

Comment: That doesn't work. Do we even use 3.0 anymore? Or is the link outdated?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Click Start -> Run `cmd` and type:

```
cd "\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation"
ServiceModelReg.exe -i
```

Answer (score 25):

If you faced this problem for the first time. with Windows 8 and IIS 8.0 make sure to activate **Windows Communication Foundation HTTP** windows feature.

1. Go to Control Panel select **"Programs and features"**
2. From the lift hand side menu select **"Turn Windows features on or off"**.
3. Expand **".Net Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)"** item
4. Finally select **"Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation"**
5. Enjoy your **WCF Servcie**.

Comment: Yours is the real answer, thank you.  Be sure to do the same for 4.0.

Comment: This is the correct, 'non-hacky', way to get rid of 404.3 error

Answer (score 10):

The problem, however, is then to re-register ASP.Net to IIS, which is explained below.

And also if you're on a 64bit machine always use Framework64 paths: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -iru

**Below is the explanation from Microsoft:**

http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/A/E/0AEB3BC1-506E-4954-8AB1-4FA2EE75985C/ReleaseNotes.docx

When attempting to run a service that receives messages over the HTTP transport, you may receive an error similar to the following:

Server Error in '/WCFApplication' Application

Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current Web request. Review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

This error can occur when IIS is installed after installing .NET Framework 4, or if the 3.0 version of the WCF Http Activation module is installed after installing IIS and .NET Framework 4.

To resolve this problem, you must use the ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool (Aspnet_regiis.exe,) to register the correct version of ASP.NET. This can be accomplished by using the –iru parameters when running aspnet_regiis.exe as follows:

aspnet_regiis.exe -iru

And credit, where it's due: [Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/39571e42-aca7-469d-8c68-aa59c2da4fcc)

Answer (score 6):

I had to tick "HTTP Activation" in "Add Role Services" within Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 3):

try to install IIS by expanding your  Internet information service and then check ASP.Net 3.5 or ASP.Net 4.5 and ISAPI.... in root of world wide.........
please look image to more help[image]

Comment: Your answer is a bit late... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I tried running ServiceModelReg and aspnet_regiis.exe with various flags and added HTTP Activation feature but it still didn't work. What finally worked was adding the following handler manually to my web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="svc-Integrated" path="*.svc" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
```

My project was running .Net 3.5 and IIS was 7.5 and 7.0.