# How do I use a command line tool to install .net 4 to IIS

Tags: wcf, silverlight, .net-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I'm trying to deploy my WCF RIA services application to our in-house server for testing.  I've been following the instructions and comments from this blog site:
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/12/10/tips-to-deploy-ria-services-troubleshoot.aspx

At the end someone points to this question:

[How to solve a "HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528324/how-to-solve-a-http-error-404-3-not-found-error)

I've been trying to run that same tool with .net 4.0 but it keeps giving me an error:

```
[Warning]The HTTP namespace reservation already exists.
```

I am running the version of the exe that I found inside of `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006`

There is also `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation` that has (what I assume is) the same exe in it, and I can use it just fine.  I've tried to un-install the 3.0 version before installing the 4.0 version, but I am still getting the same warning and failure.  Has anyone successfully done this with .net 4.0?

Comment: I am very confused - when should you run the one in 3.0 or the one in 4.0? The MS page for WCF 4 says run the 3.0 version? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012.aspx  (I want  WCF 4.0)  -does it make a difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally managed to get this to work.  I followed the instructions found [Here](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/05/21/the-iis-7-team-rocks.aspx) and I removed an HTTP namespaces that was referencing Temporary_Listen_Addresses.  after I did that I was able to successfully run the ServiceModelReg tool and install the stuff with .NET 4.0

In a nutshell:

```
netsh http show urlacl
netsh http delete urlacl url=INSERT THE RESERVED URL NAME HERE
```